# Multiple Transaction managers in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, transactionmanager

I want to use two transaction managers as follows

```
 <bean id="transactionManagerReadOnly" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryReadOnly" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManagerReadWrite" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryReadWrite" />
    </bean>
```

and in my code there are tx:annotation-driven tags are present such as follows

```
 <tx:annotation-driven  mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManagerReadWrite"/>

  <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManagerReadOnly"/>
```

but I read somewhere that there should be only one tx:annotation-driven present and refer another transaction manager by specifying in @Transaction tag such as folows

```
@Transactional("transactionManagerReadWrite")
@Transactional("transactionManagerReadOnly")
```

Following are my questions and queries

1. Which transaction manager is considered as a valid candidate for `@Transactional` if there are two transaction managers present and two `tx:annotation-driven` tags present in configuration file if we don't specify the name of transaction  manager explicitly in `@Transactional` annotation ?
2. What would be the mode of second transaction manager if it is recommended to have only one `tx:annotation-driven` tag in application and  we specify the mode in `tx:annotation-driven` tag only ?
   i.e. springs default mode is proxy mode and I want to use two transaction manager's with aspectj mode
3. How to specify `aspectj` mode for second transaction manager if we can use only one `tx:annotation-driven` tag and default mode is `proxy` mode in spring ?

Comment: You can have only 1 `<tx:annotation-driven />` and what you specify there is the default transaction manager used. You also specify the mode to use (proxy or aspectj) this will apply to all `@Transactional` annotation. By default it will use the default tx manager **unless** there is one specified in the `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: @M.Deinum how to speicfy aspctj mode for second transaction manager ?

Comment: You don't need to specify that... The mode is set globally and doesn't depend on which tx manager is used. What it does is how to interpret `@Transactional` annotations either proxy or aspectj, and has nothing to do with how many tx managers you have.

Comment: So you mean to say in my case aspectj set for transactionManagerReadWrite will be applied for transactionManagerReadOnly also even though I don't specify  transactionManagerReadOnly  in tx:annotation driven tag ?

Comment: Yes. There is only a single transaction aspect and that uses either the tx manager as specified in the `@Transactional` or the default if none is specified. It doesn't rely on which and how many tx managers you have which mode is applied. The fact that there is only a single transaction aspect is also the reason there can be only a single `<tx:annotation-driven />` as that will configure the globally used (the default) transaction manager.

Comment: @M.Deinum do you have any documentation link available regarding this?

Comment: @M.Deinum kindly add your comments in answer section

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a single `<tx:annotation-driven />` as that configured how `@Transactional` annotations are handled. You specify the mode (`proxy` or `aspectj`) and the default transaction manager to associate with `@Transactional` annotations.

The aspect is thus either applied through proxies (mode `proxy`) or load or compile time weaving (mode `aspectj`). There is just 1 aspect and that aspect either uses the default transaction manager or the one defined in the `@Transactional` annotation.

Given you specify the `aspectj` mode and `transactionManagerReadWrite` as the default transaction manager

```xml
<tx:annotation-driven  mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManagerReadWrite"/>
```

Now when using a plain `@Transactional` it will use `transactionManagerReadWrite`, when using `@Transactional("transactionManagerReadOnly")` it will use the `transactionManagerReadOnly`. Either one will be weaved in as `aspectj` is used as the mode to apply transactions.

Comment: so aspectj mode will be applied to both  transaction managers i.e. to transactionManagerReadWrite and transactionManagerReadOnly

Comment: the mode has nothing to do with transaction managers... There is only 1 component applying transactions the transaction aspect. The mode specifies how that is applied...

Comment: Got you Thanks for information. do you have any documentation link available?

Comment: Curious as to how propagation would work; if on a top level I use `@Transactional("managerA")`, and from there a method without a specific manager is called (so just a `@Transactional` annotation), would it continue with `managerA` or would it create a new transaction using the default manager?